# Mapping/translating an object to another in F#

Tags: linq, f#

I'm a beginner to F# and playing around with it, until I faced this problem. I searched for it but couldn't find anything. I want to mutate an object into another. I have  Geolocation object With lots of properties, two of them the **Latitude and Longitude.** I want to create a new dynamic object but using a pipe or a select operator,  with only that subset of properties

```
let customLocation = OtherPlace.Geolocation ....
```

how can I do this?

Comment: `type Loc = |LL of float * float`?

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make a pipeline from my object to the new object?

Comment: `Something |> fun t -> LL(t.Latitude,t.Longitude)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to solve this sort of problem is to create a discriminated union with a single case. You could use a straight type alias, but you would lose a small amount of type safety.  To define the type use:

```
type Loc = |LL of float * float
```

and then you can create instances with something like:

```
Something |> fun t -> LL(t.Latitude,t.Longitude)
```

or the simpler version:

```
LL(something.Latitude,something.Longitude)
```

Answer (score 4):

let's say you have an array of OtherPlace.Geolocation

```
geoLocations :  OtherPlace.Geolocation array
```

you can then, depending on your need :

- use a **tuple** (which is just a special case of a record)

.

```
 //of type (double * double) array
let g = geoLocations |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Latitude, x.Longitude)
```

- create a **record type** (nb : a tuple is just a record with positional names)

.

```
type Position = {Latitude : double; Longitude : double}

//of type Position array
let g = geoLocations |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Latitude, x.Longitude)
```

For small local need, a tuple is better suited but can become unwieldy.

Records allow you to better structure the program

---

Union case should be used to differentiate between different things, that still represent some common concept.
For instance you could have the position to be expressed in different system

```
type GeoPosition = | LaTLong of double * double
                   | WGS84 of double * double
                   | ...

//of type GeoPosition array
let g = geoLocations |> Array.map (fun x -> LatLong (x.Latitude, x.Longitude))
```

PS : if you use F# 3.1 you have one additional sugar for naming union type fields as shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2013/06/27/announcing-a-pre-release-of-f-3-1-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)

Comment: Nice explanation, I will use Records then.